# Multiple Query_Posts

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I am trying to put a query_posts inside a WP_query.

Anything after my query_posts doesn't work properly. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'featured' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
<div id="latest">
    <h2>The Latest Issue</h2>
    <div id="breaking-bg">
        <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
          the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        ?>  
    </div>
    <div class="breaking">  
        <div id="featured-content">
            <p class="datetime"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <h4>What's Inside:</h4>
            <ul class="preview olLoop">
            <?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'Magazine Preview', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );  echo $featuredImage;?>" rel="lightbox" title="">
                Photo Preview
                <br>
                <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>

            <h3>Available Now.<br>
            For Free.</h3>

            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'magazine_url', true ); ?>" class="button read-it" target="_blank">Read It <i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i></a>
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'magazine_url', true); ?>
        </div>

</div><!--/breaking-->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong?

Comment: The last a tag, where it tries to get the custom field "magazine_url" doesnt work. When I get rid of the query_posts inside of the entire WP_query, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, first, is `query_posts`. [Please don't use `query_posts`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376) Just don't. Create a new query just like you did when you created `$loop`.

Second, your inner loop alters the `global` variable `$post`. You need to reset that with [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after that inner loop runs. I believe that will take care of it.